# C# DLL hide some source code functions with main logic

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dllimport

I am trying to create C# library, but when I import the library to another visual studio project I can see the dll source code. I know that you can decompile DLL with some reverse engineering methods, but I hope that visual studio would not show the library source code in reference manager.

Am I doing something wrong in building process of my library?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Build for production and use [obfuscation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/dotfuscator/?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an obfuscator.  It's not a bullet-proof strategy but it will take the complexity of decompiling your code to the next level.  Also keep in mind that unless you have [debug symbols removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-build-settings-dialog-box-csharp?view=vs-2022), when you use the library on your local machine it will basically just refer back to your source code directly.

Here is a short list of the many obfuscation tools that are out there:

https://gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net

https://orangeheap.blogspot.nl

https://github.com/XenocodeRCE/neo-ConfuserEx

And a widely used commercial product:

https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/